# Normal map artifacts/ flat shading

Tags: normal-map, artifacts

I found some posts about this problem and some of it nearly fixed it. But it's still weird.

I have a sphere with a texture and a normal map. Originally the sphere had one vertex at the top and bottom and triangles to the quads (like a default sphere). This caused some shading issues and I edited the top and bottom.

Now my normal map somehow messes up the shading.

But only in a few conditions:

1. Depending on the light, on the top where it's brighter it looks better, in the shadow it's really awful.
2. In material preview mode it's looks completely bad, but when changing to rendered view (cycles) it's most of the time fine, but sometimes you can still see the problems.

When I remove the normal map the problems are gone, so I think the normal map is the problem here.

Do you guys have any suggestions for me?

I created the normal map myself in photoshop based on the texture. I never did that before and maybe that's the problem.

I also changed the brightness of the map itself (in photoshop) because that gave me some better result, and a reference file (with a basketball) had a overall "brighter" normal map, so I thought, well I make it also a little brighter.

I know my normal map s set to sRGB instead of no color, because that messes everything up even more.

[image: Normal map artifacts]

[image]

Comment: Multiple issues.  You seem to have an sRGB space normal map, which Blender doesn't handle well (not entirely sure why it chokes on them, but it does.)  Your UV mapping at the poles is totally screwed up, but that wouldn't be a problem if the polar normal map was base normals, linear color 0.5, 0.5, 1.0-- but it's not.  Recommended: convert to linear color, then manually hard paint the polar regions (+-Y borders of image) to 0.5,0.5,1.0 lavender.  Generally speaking, hand painting a normal map is hard and a bad idea; you seem to have done relatively well, but you'd be better off using a bump.

Comment: And you certainly never change brightness of a normal map.

Comment: @Nathan Thank you very much. Not much of that tells me a lot, but it‘s a start for me to research. Some clarification: I didn‘t handpaint the normal map. It‘s done with the Photoshop filter. And the original basketball normal map had a brighter purplish color, so I thought I can just brighten it. I didn‘t fix the UV, you are right. But because it‘s white I don‘t think that matters a lot. Do you have some more „keywords“ for me to research about the „0.5 0.5 1.0“? I‘m not 100% sure what these values stand for

Comment: Those numbers are RGB values, corresponding to the 0,0,1 vector, which in a tangent space normal map means the same as the base normal.  PS is almost certainly using a bump mapping algorithm to create the normal map, in which case *adjacent, identical* colors should correspond to that normal (not the same thing as white) but not if you then brighten it.  Whatever PS is using to feed the bump, you should just use a bump yourself.  Normal maps are vectors, not colors, and you'll screw stuff up if you treat them as colors.